Wordpress add global & classic inline css programmatically
How is it possible to put the Wordpress global and classic inline css style into the head?
I do not use the main function wp_head() so I am looking for a programmatically answer.
What I tried so far
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_style('global-styles');
    wp_register_style('global-styles');
});

and
add_action('init', function(){
    wp_enqueue_global_styles();
});

But this does not make sense.
Hope somebody has the answer or can put me in the right direction.

The wp_head() function is what allows you, the theme and plugins to inject stuff in the <head> section of your site. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use it?

Just looked in the core code to see which function is responsible for this
If you want the global-styles-inline-css add manually put the code below between  and 
<style><?php print_r(wp_get_global_stylesheet()); ?></style>

